# ChartJs: x-axes min and max value not working

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0

I am querying the labels/x-axis from the database based upon the user input. for example user query the data starting from `10 march 2017` but the data i got `16 march 2017` because from `10 to 16` data is not available.

**Problem:** now when i plot this array of dates on the `x-axes` it starts the data from 16 but i want to show the `x-axes` starting from the `10-march-2017`. I tried to specify this as :

```
                ticks: {
                min: $("#date_to").datepicker("getDate"),
                max: $("#date_from").datepicker("getDate"),
                fontSize: 10,
                display: true,
                }
```

Still it is showing the data starting from 16 neglecting the dates specify by the user. Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have them the wrong way round. Min would be from, and max would be to.

```
           ticks: {
            min: $("#date_from").datepicker("getDate"),
            max: $("#date_to").datepicker("getDate"),
            fontSize: 10,
            display: true,
            }
```

Comment: it does not matter because it just have to show the data there.